# Sidebar position "semi" fixed css

Tags: css, position, fixed, sidebar

How do i get a fixed sidebar like the one containing the social buttons on this site:

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/11/social-media-buttons-and-icon-sets.html

I want my sidebar to be fixed to the top of my screen when i scroll down but on the top of the page there must be an absolute position it so that it stops following the browser as i scrool.

Currently I am just using:

```
#sidebar { position:fixed; }
```

But this does not give it an absolute position when reaching the top of the page.

Thank you

Comment: I can not understand why you need to make it absolute.

Comment: you can't do this effect with css alone you need to use javascript/jquery

Comment: If you think you got a correct answer, could you please mark it as accepted :) thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper"><div class="abs" id="sidebar"></div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.abs { position: absolute; }

.fixed {
position: fixed;
top: 30px !important;}

#sidebar {
top: 150px;
left: 0;
height: 100px;
width: 20px;
background-color: #ccc;}

.wrapper {
height: 1500px;
padding: 20px;}
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    var scrollReference = 10;
    if (scrollPosition >= scrollReference) {      
        $("#sidebar").addClass('fixed');   
    } else {
        $("#sidebar").removeClass('fixed');
        $("#sidebar").addClass('abs');
    };
});
```

**DEMO of this code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/B3jZ5/6/

```
<div class="wrapper">
```

is the example of content.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this plugin:

https://code.google.com/p/sticky-panel/