# Scrolling with a button which should have a fixed position

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get a button to work which should keep on scrolling. The website is http://mkg-praxisklinik-muenchen.de/. It is the green button "Termin vereinbaren" on the bottom left side. This should stay sticky (fixed position) while I am scrolling the page.

The problem is that if the page is too short the button does not appear at all - as also on responsive designs.

I have tried all the known css workarounds without success. Does anybody know of a javascript solution?

Comment: In short: You need to detect the height of viewport and the position of vertical scroll-bar so that you can attach a `fixed` class to the element when it's needed. You could follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16089743/1725764

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using position: fixed, you need to set a position property like top,bottom,left,right

In this case, all i did was add

```
bottom: 50px;
```

and it works like you expected it to.

Also, no need for margins when you are using positioning.

I also noticed you have a relative container, probably not the best way to go about a fixed element. I would remove the container all together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bottom` CSS rule in addition to `position: fixed`

```
a.round-button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -150px;
    transition: bottom ease 0.5s;
}
```

And if you want the button to be expanded on mouse hover, you can try:

```
a.round-button:hover {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

[A simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ebfgmn9y/)

[More info about CSS bottom property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp)